# How did Rey stand up to Kylo Ren?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

OK, I know Rey was probably taught in the ways of the force from a young age and that Kylo Ren was injured. But that still does not explain how someone like Kylo Ren who was far more experienced in many aspects of the force than a once young-ling was not able to quickly dispatch Rey with a few quick moves.

How was this possible?

EDIT: I am not suggesting that Rey was untrained, however I am asking how someone who was more versed in the force could not dispatch someone who is not with-in a few strokes of their light saber? And no question specifically addresses why Rey was able to stand up to Kylo Ren?

Comment: @Richard What I really am confused on is you duped a question to another dupe.

Comment: @bleh - The accepted answer on the dupe I picked is closer to this question than the answers on the other dupe. They're both pretty darned close though.